# How to dynamically name files in lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

Here's some sample code:

```
dat <- data.frame(test1=runif(100,0,1),
                  test2=runif(100,0,1),
                  test3=runif(100,0,1))

variable_of_interest <- "test1"

dat_multi <- 3


test_save <- function(dat, x_seq) {
  saveRDS(dat, file=paste0("data/", variable_of_interest,"_", x_seq,".RDS"))
}



test_func <- function(dat, dat_multi,x) {
  res <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dat*dat_multi))
  
  dat_test <- rbind(melt(res$test1) %>% mutate(Var = "First_Testing_1"),
                    melt(res$test2) %>% mutate(Var = "Different_Testing_2"),
                    melt(res$test3) %>% mutate(Var = "Very_Different_Testing_3"))
  
  test_save(dat_test,x)
}

x_seq <- 1:3

lapply(x_seq, function(x) test_func(dat, dat_multi, x))
```

Just looking to save files with the `variable_of_interest` and the iteration in the filename:

```
data/test1_1.RDS
data/test1_2.RDS
data/test1_3.RDS
```

Comment: Is the `dat_multi` constant i.e. 3 or you are looping with `lapply(seq_len(dat_multi), function(x) test_func(dat, x))` also the `test_save` should be then `test_save(dat_test, dat_multi)`

Comment: That wouldn't work if the `test_funct` doesn't have an `x` argument

Comment: the dat_multi is an unrelated data step to the save

Comment: In the current function, the primary issue is `res$` as `res` is a `matrix` from the previous step `as.matrix`

Comment: Also, the `rbind` steps can be made compact `names(res) <- paste0("Testing_", seq_len(ncol(res)));
  melt(res)`

Comment: Ah I got the iteration to save. Took a bit of making sure it was being passed to all the necessary calls.

Comment: I noticed that you changed to 'First_testing1', et.c.  You can make those changes in `names(res) <- c("First_testing1', ...`

Comment: To just drop all the mutates? I'm wanting a single variable of names within the data.frame for eventual dataviz

Comment: yes, `melt` automatically create two columns i.e. the name column and the value.  So, you don't have to do this with `rbind` on single columns

Comment: Thoughts I how I might add this to the melt?

 `mutate(time = melt(res$t) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE) %>% rep(85 * 19),`

Comment: You just need to replace the line in my code `names(res) <- paste0("Testing_", seq_len(ncol(res)))` to `names(res) <- c(""First_Testing_1", "Different_Testing_2", "Very_Different_Testing_3")`

Comment: Sorry, it's a separate question from the example code. I'm having to melt the time step and multiply it by the number of my model variables. I'm just running that line after the naming step.

Comment: can you please post as a new question so that it becomes more clear. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop can be

```
lapply(x_seq, function(x) test_save(dat, x))
```

---

It is better to use a different lambda name than the object name already created in the global env.  Also, if 'dat' is the same, then the lambda function can have a single argument

---

In the updated function, there are some issues in the code i.e. `$` is used for extraction on a `matrix` object.  Instead, it would be `[` .  It can be made compact with

```
test_func <- function(dat, dat_multi, x) {
  res <- as.matrix(dat*dat_multi)
  names(res) <- paste0("Testing_", seq_len(ncol(res)))
  test_save(melt(res), x)
 
}
lapply(x_seq, function(x) test_func(dat, dat_multi, x))
```

Comment: I need to re-think my example code, my save code is a function within a function and this isn't working. It says another variable is missing.

Comment: @SCDCE Is the `dat` same or different.  If it is different, then use `Map` i.e. `Map(test_save, list(dat1, dat2, dat3), x_seq)`

Comment: I've edited to simulate a bit of what's going on. Basically running a model which outputs a matrix, melting it into a data.frame and naming the variable, and saving each iteration. There are tons more munging steps as well but I didn't include those.

Comment: @SCDCE where are you passing the `x` in the `test_func` i.e.  `test_save(dat_test,x)

Comment: I've made some more edits, I only tried just in the function

Comment: Added some more updates. The naming has no simple convention.